# Are there any consequences of a Critical Failure on attack rolls?

Tags: attack, attack-roll, pathfinder-2e, fumbles

At "*Attack rolls*" on page 446 of CRB I could not find anything.

For generic weapon attack rolls, is there a difference between Failures and Critical Failures?

Comment: Paizo released a Critical Fumble deck along with the Critical Hit deck for Pathfinder 2e, but those may fall under the category of house rules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There is usually no additional penalty for a Critical Failure on attack rolls.

Per [PHB p10](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=11),

> Similarly, failing the check by 10 or more is a critical failure (sometimes called a fumble). This *sometimes* results in additional negative effects. [...] Note that **not all checks have a special effect on a critical success or critical failure** and such results should be treated just like an ordinary success or failure instead.

Because, as you noted, there is no Critical Failure entry for [Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=89) Actions, there is no additional penalty without some other ability being in use.

---

The Fighter Feat [Dueling Riposte](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=389) is an example of a situation that changes this.

> **Trigger** A creature within your reach critically fails a Strike against you.

There are also abilities baked into some Bestiary creatures (however they seem generally rare at the time of this writing). The [Gimmerling](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=228) (Bestiary p177) is one such example.

> **Trip Up** [reaction] **Trigger** A creature critically fails a melee attack to hit the gimmerling or moves into a space within the gimmerling’s treacherous aura.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that some monsters also have reactions that trigger off a critical failure on an attack.